# square bracket operator [ ] overloading in a MyString linked list class c++

Tags: c++

I'm running into a problem of my c++ programming class project, and it's due 12am tonight, I have only one problem left and it really drives me crazy.

Here is a problematic part of my code:

```
MyString &StrList::operator[](int i){

    MyString *temp = new MyString;
    struct Node * ptr = list.head;

    if (i == 0){
        return *(MyString *)((list.head)->data);
    }
    else{

        for (int index = 0; index == i; index++){
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
        temp = (MyString *)(ptr->data);
        return *temp;
    }
}

const MyString& StrList::operator[](const int i) const{
//return ((StrList&)*this)[i];


MyString *temp = new MyString;
struct Node * ptr = list.head;

if (i == 0){
    return *(MyString *)((list.head)->data);

    //return *temp;
}
else{

    for (int index = 0; index == i; index++)
        ptr = ptr->next;

    temp = (MyString *)(ptr->data);

return *temp;
}
```

}

And Here is the problem:

```
//main.cpp
StrList s1 {5 4 3 2 1 0}
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    cout<<s1[i]<<endl;
```

However, all the 6 numbers print out is 5, which is the first element of the list. 
Can anyone point out what is wrong here? any comment/opinion/experience is welcomed! I really need to solve this problem by tonight 12am, much appreciated, Thank you!!!

Comment: `for (int index = 0; index == i; index++)` look closely at what this does.

Comment: What happens when you step through in a debugger?

Comment: the condition on the for loop is wrong.. you want index != i

Comment: Unrelated: You never use the `MyString` created in the first line.  Either eliminate `temp` entirely, or at least replace `new MyString` with `nullptr` or `NULL` or `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Look closely at this:

```
    for (int index = 0; index == i; index++){
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
```

Shouldn't that be...

```
    for (int index = 0; index != i; index++){
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
```

?